# Kafka is not restarting - cleared logs, disk space. Restarted but it turns off again and again

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We are a talent system and have installed *Zookeeper* and *Kafka* on our AWS instance to send our requests to the core engine to get matches.

On our UI we are getting the error:

> NoBrokersAvailable

and when we check *Kafka* is down. We restart it and it's still down. We checked for the logs and cleared it and also we checked cleared disk space.

Still the same problem of *Kafka* not starting. What should we do?

[image]

Comment: What does it say in kafka and zookeeper logs when you start ?

Comment: More logs would be helpful. Normally, if you have an emergency, restarting the server helps. Also, make sure that Zookeeper is up and running and that it has the minimum quorum.